# Update Property When Another Property Changed

Tags: c#, properties, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

I want to update `Name` property of a class whenever matching `ID` changes, I get the matching `Name` from web reference.

For example:

```
class Request 
{
    private int xID;

    public int XID 
    {
        get =>
        set 
        {
             xID = value;
             XName = value;
        }
   }

   private string xName;

   public string XName 
   {
       get => xName 
       set
       {
           xName = new FillUser(value).FullUserName   // the usage of the WebReference,
                                                      // create an object with all user credentials 
       }
    }

    public int YID { get; set; }
    public string YName { get; set; }
}
```

So I have multiple ID's and all of them has matching name and all of them will work the same.

Except ID value will be change depending on the prop.

Looking for best practice way to solve this problem - thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I find It's creating custom Attribute for those property,
and then under that category you multiple ways.
You can send argument to the prop attribute with name of the dependent attribute,

Or generic method,
and etc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should not do `XName = value;`

You write a method say ChangeId and then put all the logic in it. The other IDs props should remain **get only.**

```
void Changex(into xid)
{
    xId = xid;
    xName = Full User.GetUserNameById(xid);
}
```

Comment: I understand but leave that aside, Its not what I've meant.
lets say I have 5 ID's, now i Need to create designated method for each of them,
all of them works the same execute the same function that return fullName from Id,

how can I do that ?  update every NAme prop when its prop ID change automatically.
Events? Attributes? somthing?